# Why is the Tkinter "LabelFrame" failing in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to figure out why I get the same error message when invoking the "LabelFrame" in Tkinter for Python3:

Error output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./example2.py", line 6, in
>   
>       labelframe_tk=LabelFrame(screen, text="LabelFrame Title") NameError: name 'LabelFrame' is not defined

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter
screen=tkinter.Tk()
screen.geometry('300x300')

labelframe_tk=LabelFrame(screen, text="LabelFrame Title")
labelframe_tk.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")

inside=Label(labelframe_tk, text="Whatever goes here!")
inside.pack()

screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's failing for exactly the reason it says: there is nothing in your code that defines `LabelFrame`.

Given how you've imported tkinter, you need to use `tkinter.LabelFrame`.

Comment: Wouldn't importing the module just import the entire function?

Comment: @xorLogic: importing the module imports the module. I don't know what you mean by "the entire function". `LabelFrame` isn't a function, and neither is the module.